# Django: how to generate/use translations messages from django.po for JavaScript (djangojs)?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I've been playing with localization on the client side. So I want to collect messages for djangojs from python and html files, but it didn't work

Django version is 1.3,
Gettext utilitest are installed in the system

`django-admin.py makemessages -d djangojs -l ru -e html,py`

Does anyone know how to generate/use translations messages from django.po for JavaScript (djangojs)?

For example I put just `ngettext("Hello world")` messages for test reasons in some `js` file and finally it doesn't get into djangojs.po file.

Sultan

Comment: What exactly did not work? Have you included the JS catalogue on your web page? Have your ran `makemessages` from your project directory?

Comment: Yes I added `javascript_catalog` script and `jsi18n` to urls, I run `makemessages` and `compilemessages`, but nothing happens

Comment: It does not create `locale/ru/djangojs.po` or it does not output the created and compiled catalogue in JS? Try including it with `language` GET parametar: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/?language=ru"></script>`

Comment: djangojs.po and catalog are generated well, but without my translation strings

Comment: What version of django are you using? Have you marked your strings for translations with `gettext` in your JS files? Try excluding `-e` parameter. Do you have `gettext` installed on your system? [Django docs ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) (see warnings) & SO [ref for django 1.2 and problems with comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879177/django-1-2-3-internationalization-makemessages-does-not-detect-all-strings)

Comment: I think the fix is included in [1.4 trunk](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7704) if its the lexer problem. Again check out [Neds answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5635552/327317) and comments. Or try with Django trunk version to see if it generates catalogue properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Django version is 1.3, I tried to exclude `-e` parameter, gettext doesn't give any warnings

Comment: I think the problem is that it really doesn't detect all translation strings, btw @rebus thank you for your time I appreciate it

Comment: Try with Django development version to be sure.

Comment: Sure I'll try, btw there is Babel/Django intergation exists http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/BabelDjango

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of this question: [Django 1.2.3 - Internationalization - makemessages does not detect all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879177/django-1-2-3-internationalization-makemessages-does-not-detect-all-strings).

Your problem has probably the same cause as mine. It is because the makemessages for javascript is a hack and sometimes doesn't get the strings marked for translation. As the gettext tools do not support javascript, the code first goes through simple transforms and is then processed as Perl.

You can find an article about it here: [A Javascript lexer in Python, and the saga behind it](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201104/a_javascript_lexer_in_python_and_the_saga_behind_it.html)

And the bug report here: [Ticket 7704](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7704). It is fixed in Django 1.4.

As my project was small, I edited the PO files directly but if yours is bigger you should use either django 1.4 RC or the patch linked in the bug report.

Comment: It seems to I've the same situation here with my "Media Management System" project I've been developing so far is relatively big

Comment: I'm trying to apply patches at Ticket 7704 but since there is no jslex for Django 1.3 I can't do this

Comment: Just use 1.4 if it is a new project, it should be out quite soon.

Comment: nowadays, gettext supports JavaScript natively [since 0.18.3](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fe9c7ded2996364f853c524b4421274717d89d5f/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py#L72-L73). Only if you're using an older version then Django transforms the JavaScript then [processes it with gettext as C](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4a412c2e659f9295973434c65b785b03acee7251/django/utils/jslex.py#L185), not Perl.